# Can a text file update data using cfinclude?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using cfinclude to output data from that cfm file.
A user will be able to update the pace/target by changing the numbers in the rates.cfm file.

I would prefer to make this into an text(txt) file.

Would this be able to be done in a text file ?

I know I can't make rates.cfm into a txt file because of cfset.
Above I'm only using part of the table, rates.cfm will have more than two variables.

```
  <cfinclude template="rates.cfm" />

        <h2>Scoreboard</h2>

        <table >
        <thead><tr><th>Category</th><th>Target</th><th>Pace </th></tr></thead>
        <cfoutput>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td> Income </td><td>$ #net_income_target#</td><td>$ #net_income_pace#</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

**rates.cfm** file

```
  <cfset net_income_target = 6.1 >
    <cfset net_income_pace = 8.3 >
```

Comment: You can create a form that submits to a .cfm page that writes to the text file.  You can also store that data in a database.

Comment: @Dan i don't think i would like it to be that complicated, just a user go to the txt file change the numbers and done, no database.

Comment: If you want to sacrifice security for simplicity, knock yourself out.

Comment: You have output that has HTML in it, and you want to serve it as a .txt file? Really? Can you pls elaborate more on your requires here, as that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Storing data to a text file and reading it back is equally as 'complicated' as persisting to a database - maybe more complicated.

Comment: @scottstroz in other words stick to cfm file, i just thought there be something out there i didnt know about that could make this happen

Comment: That is not what I said. What is the purpose of the include? Do you want it to be user editable? It is really difficult to understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: yes i want to make it user editable.
a text file where a user can enter the numbers and it will update the html table, first time i use cfinclude, but doing it the wrong way

Comment: Do you know what, @anatp_123: the more you write, the less I understand you. What's the correlation you're seeing between text files and data entry?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. Change your file name from rates.cfm to rates.txt and change `<cfinclude template="rates.cfm" />` to `<cfinclude template="rates.txt" />`